# suppress Javadoc

Tags: jaxb, javadoc

when i compile a JAXB schema the generated classes are decorated with generic Javadoc comments.

is it somehow possible to suppress generating these comments?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to suppress JAXB's Javadoc?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Annotation to disable JavaDocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928467/annotation-to-disable-javadocs)

> Not if you're using Sun's JavaDocs tool.
>
> They have [a feature request](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4058216) for it, but it's been in low priority since 1997.
>
> You can write a custom doclet to overcome this, or use a 3rd-party tool (DocFlex or such).

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question: he asks for a way not to generate javadoc when generating classes, this answer says there is no way to exclude classes when processing javadoc to generate documentation.