# how to remove javadoc with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jaxb, javadoc

As it is mentioned in 
[Annotation to disable JavaDocs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928467/annotation-to-disable-javadocs) I was not  able to disable generation of Javadocs by JAXB when generating Java classes from XSD.

I clearly do not need documentation for hundreds of getters/setters. Is there a way to automate deletion of javadocs instead of manually selecting and deleting them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution that works so far is to use replace functionality with regex search enabled and to use the following regex for selection `\/\*\s*[\s\S]*?\*\/$`, then replace found javadoc entries with an empty string.

Comment: You may also want to add `\n` if you don't want to leave an empty line in place of the old Javadoc. I also added `^\s` at the start to ensure the start of the line is correctly deleted. This leaves us with `^\s*\/\*\s*[\s\S]*?\*\/$\n`

Answer (score 2):

Someone should develop a plugin that loads and unloads the javadoc...on demand...so those that are puritanical and want absolutely no javadoc (setters and getters for sure dont make sense for javadoc) can remove them with one click.

Comment: go for it, be someone ;)